# Can't add scopes to my Azure AD application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to add new permissions to my Azure AD Application, however when I try, it gets stuck on a loading screen that has now lasted for more than half an hour. I tried different browsers (firefox, Chrome, Edge) with no different result.

[A screenshot of the loading screen can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnxR5.png)

EDIT:
Aditionally, I tried creating a new App, and I even created a whole new Account, however it didn't work.

Comment: You can create a new application and try again.

Comment: @TonyJu Nope, didn't work. I even tried creating a new Account, and it didn't work :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apearantly, adding new Scopes worked by using preview.portal.azure.com, even as far as to the normal Azure AD portal. I don't know why it worked, but somehow it did.

Answer (score 1):

It might get stuck on the loading screen due to cache/cookies. I know it's kind of a pain, but you can try deleting the cache/cookies and opening an incognito window which should help it load.

If the issue persists it may require deeper troubleshooting. If you send me an email I can open a support case for you.

I checked Azure Status and it doesn't seem like there are any reported outages that could be causing this.

Comment: Thanks for the help1, but both steps don't work. If you give me your E-Mail Adress, I can send you an E-Mail though.

Comment: Thanks for following up. It's AzCommunity@microsoft.com

Comment: I've sent an E-Mail there a few days ago, but I still didn't get an answer. Is that normal?

Comment: Just replied and need your sub ID. You should be able to add a free trial subscription if you want. Looks like it's being tracked over Q&A as well.

Comment: Since I haven't heard from you in a while, so I also posted my request on your Q&A site, and there I received faster support. I am currently in contact with one of your colleagues about this matter, and I will post the answer here, as soon as I learn more.